# Stacktrace incomplete when throwing from async catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Why is there no async stacktrace when rethrowing an asynchronous exception? With node 12+, the exception when running [the following code](https://github.com/phihag/async-rethrow-stacktrace-example/blob/master/crash.js):

```
async function crash() {
    try {
        await (async () => {throw new Error('dead');})();
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error('rethrow');
    }
}

async function foo() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1));
    await crash();
}

async function entrypoint() {
    try {
        await foo();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.stack);
    }
}
entrypoint();
```

is woefully incomplete:

```
Error: rethrow
    at crash (/async-stackt/crash.js:6:15)
```

I found a workaround [by defining the exception in the beginning of `crash()`](https://github.com/phihag/async-rethrow-stacktrace-example/blob/master/workaround.js), which yields a much nicer:

```
Error: rethrow
    at crash (/workaround.js:2:17)
    at foo (/workaround.js:12:11)
    at async entrypoint (/workaround.js:17:9)
```

This is not optimal, since the error has to be constructed in advance whether it is needed or not, and the stacktrace is somewhat imprecise.

Why is the stack trace incomplete when throwing an error from an async catch block? Is there any workaround or change to the code to get a complete stack trace in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That stack trace is showing you what's ON the stack at that time.  When you make an asynchronous call such as `setTimeout()`, it runs the `setTimeout()` which registers a timer that will fire some time in the future and then it continues execution.  Since you're using `await` here, it pauses the execution of `foo()`, but it continues execution of the code after where `foo()` was called.  Since that's also an `await`, it continues executing the code that called `entrypoint()`.  After that finishes, the stack is entirely empty.

Then, sometime later, your timer fires and its callback gets called with a completely clean stack.  In your case, the `setTimeout()` callback just calls `resolve()` which then triggers a promise to schedule its resolve handlers to run on the next event loop tick.  That returns back to the system and the stack frame is again empty.  On that next tick of the event loop, the promise resolve handlers are called and that satisfies the `await` on that promise which is inside a function context.  When that `await` is satisfied, the rest of that function starts to execute.

When that function gets to the end of its execution, the interpreter knows that this was a suspended function context.  There is no `return` from the function to happen because that already happened earlier.  Instead, since this is an `async` function, the end of the function execution resolves the promise that this `async` function returns.  Resolving that promise then schedules its resolve handlers to be called on the next tick of the event loop and then it returns control back to the system.  The stack frame is again empty.  On that next tick of the event loop, it calls the resolve handlers which satisifies the `await` in the `await foo()` statement and the `entrypoint()` function can continue to run, picking up where it was last suspended.

So, the key here is that when the timer goes off, execution goes from `foo` back to `entrypoint`, not via a stack and a `return` statement (that function already returned awhile ago), but via promises getting resolved. So, at the time the timer goes off and you then call `crash()`, the stack is indeed empty except for the function call to `crash()` itself.

This concept of an empty stack when promises are resolved goes to the heart of how an `async` function actually works so it's important to understand that.  You have to remember that it pauses the internal execution of the function containing the `await`, but as soon as it hits the first `await`, it immediately causes the function to return a promise and the the callers continue further execution.  The caller is not paused unless they also so an `await` in which case the callers of the caller continuing executing.  At some point, somebody gets to continue executing and eventually, it returns control back to the system with a now-empty stack.

The timer event (or some other promise triggering event) then gets called with a completely empty stack frame with no remnants from the original call sequence.

Unfortunately, the only work-around I'm aware of now is to do what you found - create the Error object earlier when the original stack is still alive.  If I remember correctly, there is a discussion about adding some features to the Javascript language to make asynchronous tracing easier.  I don't remember the details of the proposal, but perhaps by remembering what the stack frame was when the function was originally called since what it is after the promise is resolved/rejected and when the Error object is created is no longer very useful.

---

In case anyone was unfamiliar with how `async` functions work and how they suspend their own execution upon the first `await`, but then `return` early, here's a little demo:

```js
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

async function stepA() {
    console.log("5");
    await stepB();
    console.log("6");
}

async function stepB() {
    console.log("3");
    await delay(50);
    console.log("4");
}

console.log("1");
stepA();
console.log("2");
```

This generates the following output.  If you follow this execution path step-by-step, you will see how each `await` causes an early return from that function and can then see how the stack frame will be empty once the promise that is being awaited gets resolved.  This is the output generated:

```
1
5
3
2
4
6
```

It's clear why `1` is first as it's the first thing to execute.

Then, it should be clear why `5` comes next when `stepA()` is first called.

Then, `stepA` calls `stepB()` so as it begins to execute, that's why we see `3` next.

Then, `stepB` calls `await delay(50)`.  That executes `delay(50)` which starts a timer and then immediately returns a promise that is hooked to that timer.  It then hits the `await` and it stops execution of `stepB`.

When `stepB` hit that `await`, it causes `stepB` at that point to return a promise that comes from the function being `async`.  That promise will be hooked to `stepB` execution eventually (in the future) getting a chance to finish all of its execution.  For now the execution of `stepB` is suspended.

When `stepB` returns its promise, that goes back to where `stepA` executed `await stepB();`.  Now that `stepB()` has returned (an unfulfilled promise), then `stepA` hits its `await` on that `unfulfilled` promise.  That suspends the execution of `stepA` and it returns a promise at that point.

So, now that the original function call to `stepA()` has returned (an unfulfilled promise) and there is no `await` on that function call, that top level code after that function call continues to execute and we see the console output the `2`.

That `console.log("2")` is that last statement to execute here so control is returned back to the interpreter.  At this point, **the stack frame is completely empty**.

Then, sometime later, the timer fires.  That inserts an event in the JS event queue.  When the JS interpreter is free, it picks up that event and calls the timer callback associated with that event.  This does only one thing (call `resolve()` on a promise) and then returns.  Calling resolve on that promise schedules that promise to trigger it's `.then()` handlers on the next tick of the event loop.  When that happens, the `await` on the line of code `await delay(50);` gets satisfied and execution of that function resumes.  We then see the `4` in the console as the last line of `stepB` executes.

After the `console.log("4");` executes, `stepB` has now finished executing and it can resolve it's `async` promise (the one returned by it earlier).  Resolving that promise tells it to schedule its `.then()` handlers for the next tick of the event loop.  Control goes back to the JS interpreter.

On the next tick of the event loop, the `.then()` handlers notify the `await` in the `await stepB();` that the promise has now been resolved and execution of `stepA` continues and now we see `6` in the console.  That is the last line of `stepA` to execute to it can resolve its `async` promise and return control back to the system.

As it turns out, there is nobody listening to the `async` promise that the call to `stepA()` returned so there is no further execution.

Comment: "If I remember correctly, there is a discussion about adding some features to the Javascript language to make asynchronous tracing easier." – aren't these the [zero-cost async stack traces](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13Sy_kBIJGP0XT34V1CV3nkWya4TwYx9L3Yv45LdGB6Q/edit)? They are already present in v8/node.js; note the `at async entrypoint` in the second stack trace in the question.

Comment: @phihag - As you can see right in your reference link, zero-cost async stack traces only work for `async` functions with some qualifications.  As soon as you have an asynchronous function that makes its own promise and returns that, the zero-cost stack traces don't help you for that.  So, there are still issues to be dealt with.

Comment: @jfriend00: The explanation in this answer applies to the way V8 worked before the "async stack traces" feature.

The fact that OP's example didn't work in Node 12 is because of a bug in V8's async stack traces functionality.  The bug was recently fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue in Node 12 and found out that it was fixed in a later version of V8: [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/2e796df56a07c0627c97e856423d7c6bbb998940%5E%21/).

Gotta wait for Node 14, I guess...

The bug had to do with the stack trace not being tracked in `catch` blocks.  So one workaround is to use the Promise's `.catch` function instead:

```
async function crash() {
    await (async () => {throw new Error('dead');})()
        .catch(e => { throw new Error('rethrow'); });
}
```